# C++ STL - equivalent of operator function object templates with assignment?

Tags: c++, stl, std

Are there assignment operator objects in C++? Like [std::plus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/plus/?kw=plus), but to do +=? (Likewise [minus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/minus/), [multiplies](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/multiplies/), [divides](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/divides/), etc.)

EDIT - Motivation:

I thought it would be preferable to avoid the extra copy by using the function objects (std::plus(), etc.) in the following code.

```
template<typename Op>
static vector<int>& memberwiseAssignOp(vector<int>& lhs, vector<int> rhs, Op op)
{
    size_t const len = rhs.size();

    if (len > lhs.size())
    {
        lhs.resize(len);
    }

    transform(lhs.begin(), lhs.end(), rhs.begin(), lhs.begin(), op);

    return lhs;
}


vector<int>& operator+=(vector<int>& lhs, vector<int> rhs)
{
    return memberwiseAssignOp(lhs, rhs, plus<int>());
}

vector<int>& operator-=(vector<int>& lhs, vector<int> rhs)
{
    return memberwiseAssignOp(lhs, rhs, minus<int>());
}
```

Comment: What did you find when you read a list of symbols provided by the standard library?

Comment: Anyway I'm not really sure how these would work, or at least how they would not be extremely confusing. Can you explain why you want them? Perhaps we can help you solve your actual problem rather than helping you with basic reading :)

Comment: This seems like an instance of [the XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). As LRiO said, back up a step and tell us the high level goal. You're likely approaching it incorrectly.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit and cdhowie, I added motivation to the question.

Comment: Can you just write such a functor yourself? They are probably not in the standard library because it's not a common need.

Comment: @cdhowie, I tried changing `plus<int>()` to `plusEquals<int>()` (defined as `template<typename T>
static T& plusEquals(T& lhs, T rhs)`...), but the Intellisense error I got indicates that it doesn't match the std::transform() parameter type.

Comment: @cp.engr That's not a functor. You want something like `template <typename T> struct plus_equals { T operator()(T & lhs, T const & rhs) const { ... } }`

Answer (score 1):

More generally than just "no, it's not there", there's the simple fact that overloads of assignment operators need to be done as member functions, so it really *can't* be done. I guess, since what we're dealing with aren't really operators though, it could be done to the extent that a function could be written to receive a non-const reference to an object, and modify the object to which that referred.

I'm not at all sure you'd gain a whole lot from this though. The types for which it made much difference would really be those types for which it was substantially cheaper to modify an existing object than to overwrite an old object with a new value.

At one time (before C++11), that may have been a fair number of types. Since the introduction of rvalue references you can get roughly the same effect (but much more cleanly) by moving from the old object to the new object, and modifying as you see fit along the way.

In theory, there are probably still a few places that wouldn't work out quite as nicely. The obvious example would be an object that (directly) contains a lot of data, so moving still basically works out to copying.

Comment: Is this really true? A function could have the signature `plus(T &a, const T &b)` and edit `a` before returning, i know there are plenty of issues for complex types, but wouldn't there be complexities in anything without a `operator + and =` overload?

Comment: @Ben: Well, certainly anything that received a non-const reference could modify its operand.

Comment: Yep, i am just saying, why *cant* it be done? If you had `plusEquals(T &a, const T &b)` you could add `b` to `a` and set `a` in the function so long as `T` has `operator=` and `operator+`? `std::plus` requires `operator+` overloads anyway, so why is this impossible?

Comment: "overloads of assignment operators need to be done as member functions, so it really can't be done" - true for pure assignment, but not for operator+=(). However, std::transform() won't take `T &plusEquals(T &a, const T &b)` as the op argument.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of [Functional Operations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional).

As you can see there are no assignment operators.

You could of course just have this functionality yourself like follows:

```
a = std::plus(a, b);
```

But this might not be helpful at all.